# How to get distinct values from nested array?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I need to get all the distinct name of color inside the content from the document whose name is "color",

Match criteria to get distinct `content.values.name` where `content.name = color`.

The Expected result:

```
[red, green, blue,tomato, sky, darkblue]
```

The example Documents:

```
[
    {
        content:[
            {
                name:"color",
                values: [ 
                  { name: "red" },
                  { name: "green" },
                  { name: "blue" }
                ]
            },
            {
                name:"extra",
                values: [ 
                  { name: "A" },
                  { name: "B" },
                  { name: "C" }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        content:[
            {
                name:"color",
                values: [ 
                  { name: "tomato" },
                  { name: "sky" },
                  { name: "darkblue" }
                ]
            },
            {
                name:"extra",
                values: [ 
                  { name: "AA" },
                  { name: "AB" },
                  { name: "AC" }
                ]
            }
           
        ]
    },
]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `$match` color `name` property and filter the main document
- `$unwind` deconstruct `content` array
- `$match` color `name` and filter sub-document
- `$unwind` deconstruct `values` array
- `$group` by null and get unique `name` from value

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { "content.name": "color" } },
  { $unwind: "$content" },
  { $match: { "content.name": "color" } },
  { $unwind: "$content.values" },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      values: { $addToSet: "$content.values.name" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bPKYXCJwXdl)